# Can I select from multiple SQL Server tables without specifying table name

Tags: sql-server, concatenation

We have a database with a metadata preventing tables having duplicate column names.  There are a ton of tables, with names like

```
product_attributes_1
product_attributes_ext
product_src_1
product_src_2
product_whatever_somenumber
```

I've written code that basically pulls on each table, and creates a hash. This works, but its really slow.

```
// split the table key to determine the object prefix(s) we need to focus on.
// a table key is XXX_key, if the key differs from that convention, typically
// it means that the current table inherits from a base table.
// For Example: publication (pub_prd_key) inherits from the product table (prd_key).
string[] tableKeys = myObject.GetKeyField().Split('_');

// loop through all of the separated table keys, and load additional properties for the current object  
// based on each table found.
for (int i = 0; i < tableKeys.Length; i++) {
    if (tableKeys[i] != "key"){
        DataClassWrapper data = FacadeClass.GetDataObject(tableKeys[i], databaseObject);
        if (data != null) {
            this.LoadAdditionalProperties(data.TablePrefix, data.TableKey);
        }
    }
}
```

I'd like to move this code to a stored procedure on the database, but I am not sure how to write something like the following in sql:

```
SELECT * 
FROM [mydb].[dbo].[product_*]
```

I'm not sure if it can even be done. I have my reasons, and mainly it's because we need to maintain base functionality with the system that provides the database for us to use. Please do not say "the column names could be duplicates". I know this, and we are 100% sure that there will not be duplicates. The rest of the system would break if there were duplicate column names. This is the reason for naming the tables this way.

Also, I cannot rename the tables. It's in the license agreement that we not modify core features and it would be near impossible anyway (the database is very old and very large with many systems relying on it).

**EDIT**: I need to call out that my stored procedure would take an `ID` (guid) that spans all of the tables since they literally inherit from each other. The result would be a hash of column_name / column_value where ID = some guid. It will literally only select a single row from each table.

Comment: You could do this with dynamic sql but even that is a kludge. Do all these tables have the same columns? If so you could use UNION to create a query with all the tables. But if the structures are different what are you expecting as output?

Comment: The tables all have different columns.  I would expect the output to be a big hash of column->value where each column has a unique identifier. I've added this to my q.

Comment: What does "a big hash" mean? You want the columns from each table in their own column? This makes no sense at all. Does order matter? You are going to have to provide some clarity to this.

Comment: I forgot to put in there that its not a list of rows. its going to return a single row from each table. A big hash what I mean is take all columns from all tables and join them, but without calling out each table name.

Comment: Why can't you simply use a join?

Comment: If a single row is going to be returned based on some criteria that you feed into this (product number or similar) then a `join` would be most appropriate. As for a stored procedure with dynamic object names (tables, views, columns, databases or otherwise) would require dynamically generated sql (in a string) and then that string would be executed/evaluated [see here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure this could be reduced to a simple join instead of this weird iteration and hash thing you are talking about. Something like this should produce the output you want.

```
select *
from product_attributes_1 pa
join product_attributes_ext pae on pae.MyKey = pa.MyKey
join product_src_1 ps1 on ps1.MyKey = pa.MyKey
join product_src_2 ps2 on ps2.MyKey = pa.MyKey
join product_whatever_somenumber pws on pws.MyKey = pa.MyKey
where pa.MyKey = @MyKey
```